# Video restarts only if it hasn't ended

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to restart an html video... The code works as long as the video has not ended. If the video ends, the restart button resets the video to the first frame but it does not play. Any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot this?

```
function restart() {
var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
video.currentTime = 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="reload" type="submit" onclick="restart()"></button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you invoke `play()` again?

Comment: Can you advise on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.play()` method, but will also need to pause the video first before calling `.play()` will work, so try this code:

```
function restart() {
    var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");

    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.play();
}
```